# How to send dm as bot after voted top.gg discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, vote, dm

```
const Discord = require(discord.js);
const client = new Discord.Client();
const Topgg = require ("@top-gg/sdk");
```

So i dont know about next code
Sorry im to early for studying in javascript

> In here im using discord.js V12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not yet requiring Discord properly. It should be `require("discord.js");` otherwise you're trying to require a non-existent variable.

Upon scrolling through the [Top.gg API Docs](https://topgg.js.org/classes/api) it looks like you can use the [webhook](https://topgg.js.org/classes/webhook#constructor) class to get when a user votes.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Discord.Client();
// top.gg example
const Topgg = require("@top-gg/sdk");
// Webhook options can be found here if you wish to include them, currently the only one is an error callback: https://topgg.js.org/interfaces/webhookoptions
// You'll have to set up a webhook on top.gg in your bot's settings
const TopWebhook = new Topgg.Webhook("authorization");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

// This example assumes you're using express
app.post("/webhook", async TopWebhook.listener(vote) => {
    let user = vote.user; // the User ID
    // get the user from their user id, then send a DM
});
```

Hopefully this helps note that this is untested so may require some tweaking, but definitely read the documentation.

Comment: So im just need write in app.post not client.on

Comment: You still need to login of course, however the Top.gg upvote listener isn't related to the Discord Client you make at all, so no events you can listen for will really make a difference.

Comment: Okay, thanks you very much